# Significato di "fare giudizio" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> ANTONIA (*a Giovanni*)     ...tu otto ore alla catena come una
>   bestia, e loro lavorano a controllare che noi **si faccia giudizio**: che si paghi la merce ai padroni quello che loro vogliono!

Questo "loro" fa riferimento ai carabinieri.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "fare giudizio" che appare nel testo. L'ho cercata nella voce "giudizio" di parecchi dizionari. Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000884.jpg) ho trovato:

> – *Fare, formare giudizio, il giudizio, i giudizi*: giudicare,  stimare,  credere ;  supporre,  conget­turare, pronosticare. 
>   [...] 
>         – Decidere, stabilire; scegliere, discernere. 
>   [...] 
>         – Operare con giustizia.
>   [...] 
>         – Fare vendetta, punire esemplarmente.
>   [...] 
>         – Usare misericordia. 
>   [...]

E un po' più avanti:

> – *Mettere, fare giudizio*: rinsavire, cambiare vita, riprendere il cammino della virtù.

Sul [dizionario Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/G/giudizio.html) si trova

> Fare, mettere giudizio, mettere la testa a posto

e sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/giudizio/) appare un esempio di "fare giudizio" come sinononimo "di parere, opinione, avviso e sim.":

> *difficilmente si può fare giudicio del futuro* (Guicciardini)

Tuttavia, a me non sembra che nessuna di queste accezioni abbia senso nel contesto del passaggio sopra citato. Il significato mi pare sia qualcosa come "agire con senno". È così?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La tua ipotesi è corretta: nel brano indicato "fare giudizio" ha il significato di "agire con giudizio" (ovvero con senno o prudentemente), ed è anche simile al significato che hai riportato dallo Hoepli:

> Fare, mettere giudizio, mettere la testa a posto

Riprendo anche il [significato di giudizio dal vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/giudizio):

> Fam., senno, riflessione, prudenza

Quasi obbligatoria la citazione da *I Promessi Sposi* del Manzoni:

> *Pedro, adelante con juicio*

Comment: Mmmm... ma la citazione del Manzoni è castigliano!   (e infatti, il personaggio che dice questo, che era esistito davvero, era catalano :)

Comment: È una frase talmente famosa da essere diventata proverbiale ;)

Comment: Curioso: provverbiale in italiano, ma non credo sia molto conosciuta nel mio paese.

Comment: Ovviamente, intendevo proverbiale in Italia, dove il romanzo del Manzoni è considerato un pilastro :)